# Java: on mac keyboard input only firing once

Tags: java, macos, input, keyboard, keyevent

The question I have is regarding how to overcome a keyboard issue. When I press certain keys like 'up' and 'down', the method keyPressed keeps on activating, but when I press keys like 'w' or 's' the method only activates once until I release and press it again. I would like to know how to simulate repeated key presses.

here is the class for input:

```
public class Input extends KeyAdapter{

    private GameObject p1;
    private GameObject p2;

    public Input(Handler handler){
        p1 = handler.object.get(0);
        p2 = handler.object.get(1);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

        System.out.println("thismethodactivated");

        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) p1.setVelY(-5);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) p1.setVelY(5);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) p1.activate(1);

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) p2.setVelY(-5);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) p2.setVelY(5);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) p2.activate(1);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) p1.setVelY(0);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) p1.setVelY(0);

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) p2.setVelY(0);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) p2.setVelY(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you watched for key press events, and key release events.  The key press event starts a timer that triggers whatever action you need on a set interval.  The key release event could then stop the timer.

If some buttons have an automatic repeating of the press/release events when the user holds the button you would need something slightly more complicated.   But that seems beyond the scope of the question.  Let me know in the comments if you need to handle that situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i figured out a way to do the same thing in another class